# How to capture a program's output, output being a file, in Python?

Tags: python, cmd, pipe, command-line-interface, io-redirection

I have a `json2xml.exe` which I execute it like:

`> json2xml.exe -i '/path/to/file.json' -o '/path/to/file.xml';`

(The names used are for explaining purposes)
The example-program takes as input a json file and outputs an xml file.

What I need is, instead of letting the program write to a file, I want to capture this output and give it as input to another `.py` program.

Is it possible with PIPES ? (I have no access to the source code of the `json2xml.exe` program.

Comment: The `.exe` sounds like some nasty Windows program, yet you tag with `bash`. Could you clarify your environment please?

Comment: ".. instead of letting the program write to a file .." but what if it always does that? Check its documentation if omitting the argument `-o` writes to `stdout`. If you can't get it to do that, there's not much you can do with Python.

Comment: @usr2564301 I was hoping if there is a way in Windows to interfere somehow on the IO operations of a program. Somewhere the program will have a command that opens a file to write it. I was thinking if there is a way to change the file descriptor and have it pointing to somewhere else (for example to the stdin of another program)

Comment: Why have you tagged this with `bash`?

Comment: You could try leaving the -o /output/file.xml off, or try -o -

Comment: https://superuser.com/a/241280